# Inject script on Shopify Admin

Tags: shopify

Is there a way to inject a script in admin side like what ScriptTag API did injecting script in online store? I am looking for a way to inject a script to add notifications on all pages of the Shopify Admin.

Comment: Would be hilarious if Shopify did allow that! Imagine the chaos and mayhem one could create if we were allowed to do that. They don't even let us write the events queue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to add any scripts inside the admin via their API.

You can still use browser extensions or userscripts but no official way to inject a scripts with the Shopify API.

Comment: I am currently exploring this question too. But what about this: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-extensions/components/actions/button you can add a button with the Admin Extensions API and make it execute some JavaScript no?

Comment: @Pierre-VerthumeLarivière haven't looked into admin extensions, can't provide any insights there.